# Strategy for combinatorics game?

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Let $m, n > 2$ be fixed integers. $A$ thinks of $n$ not necessarily distinct integers, $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$, such that $1 \le x_i \le m$ for all $1 \le i \le n$. For each query, $B$ chooses and tells $A$ $2n$ integers, $a_i,b_i (1 \le i \le n)$, such that $1 \le a_i \le b_i \le m$ for each $i$. (Note that $a_i$ can be equal to $b_i$ for some $i$.)

$A$ replies "Bounded" if $a_i \le x_i \le b_i$ for ALL $i$ in the range $[1,n]$. Otherwise, even if it is not true for just one value of $i$, $A$ replies "Out of Bound".

Find the minimum number of queries $B$ needs to guess all of $A$'s numbers correctly.

This is a question I thought of myself. I asked a similar question before, where $n=3$ and $m=10$.

Comment: Please provide some context of the question. For this type of questions, the most important is perhaps "where did you get it from?" as we don't know whether it comes from an ongoing contest.

Comment: I asked a similar question before, where $n=3$ and $m=10$. At that time, I thought of it myself. So it is definitely not from an ongoing contest.

Comment: Then it would be better if you edit your question to add this piece of information, preferably with some of your own thoughts/works on the question.

Comment: If $\operatorname{Opt}(n,m)$ is the optimal number of guesses, then 
$$
\lceil n\log_2 m \rceil\le \operatorname{Opt}(n,m)\le n\lceil \log_2 m\rceil
$$
Combined, these prove that $\operatorname{Opt}(n,m)\in \Theta(n\log m)$, and moreover the difference between $\operatorname{Opt}(n,m)$ and $n\log_2 m$ is at most $n$. I doubt that you can say anything much stronger in general.

Comment: Here is a solution that does strictly better than the upper bound : $m = n = 3$ in 5 queries.
First query : [1,2],[1,2][1,3]. It split in Bounded (B) 12 solutions and not bounded (NB) 15 solutions. If B, this is trivial in 4 queries, if NB, second query : [1,3],[2,3],[2,3]. B:8 solutions and NB : 7 solutions. If B, query [1,1][1,3][1,3]. If B or NB, this is trivial in two queries. Back to last one (NB with 7 solutions) if NB, query [1,3],[3,3][1,3]. It split B : 3 solutions and NB : 4 solutions. B is trivial in 2 queries, if NB, query [1,3][1,3][1,1], and then this is trivial.

Comment: It has a lot in common with mastermind, I guess it is NP-hard to get an optimal solution